# what is difference between values 'react' and 'react-jsx' for 'jsx' property in compiler options of tsconfig

Tags: reactjs, compilation, jsx, tsconfig

if we take a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#basic-usage
 there are a few more values added to jsx property namely 1.  react-jsx and 2. react-jsxdev

what is the practical benefit of `react-jsx` over `react`?

Comment: if someone can add the usefulness of react-jsxdev it would be nice!

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10025#issuecomment-731754876) is all I was able to find on `react-jsxdev`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my observation and reading from below two links
1. https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html
2.https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#basic-usage
If we use `react-jsx` instead of `react`, ts compiler will output _jsx(), instead of React.createElement()
Thus we can avoid importing React in file where we are defining component, just for using jsx syntax